# Mobile view for netlify device not working

Tags: html, css, netlify

The CSS for this website works perfectly fine on my computer, as in the desktop version and the mobile version made by media queries, but when I view it on my mobile device, the CSS just stops working. The website link: https://lighthearted-basbousa-3c2db6.netlify.app/, the repo link https://github.com/hetyug04/portfolioV7. It’s hosted on netlify but I havent had problems with it before. Here is the mobile view from my phone [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, and apparantely it was because I was nesting my css styling in the stylesheet, once I denested the styles, the CSS started working for mobile browsers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Cool that you sovled it, here are the supporred browsers: https://caniuse.com/css-nesting

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is working on smaller screen sizes.

Using the browser's dev tools I could see that you have a media query with `display: none` on the intro class. This affects screens smaller or equal to 1015px. If you change or remove the media query, your output will change.

Not sure why it is there and if the removal will completely resolve your issue, but checking this should be your first step.

There are some other issues, such as overflow and incorrect width, maybe you want to check out the [mobile-first design approach](https://medium.com/@Vincentxia77/what-is-mobile-first-design-why-its-important-how-to-make-it-7d3cf2e29d00).

Comment: The display: none is intentional, and the css works on the browser dev tools perfectly fine, but if you were to visit the website on an actual mobile device, the css stops working

Comment: Works for me in Chrome on Android. What device/browser are you using?

Comment: Iphone 13, and I tried safari and chrome

Comment: Alot of my friends are having the same problem as me, theyre getting the same mobile view

Comment: Your CSS, at least the nav (which is condensed on your screenshot) and the titleDesc class (which is black instead of white on your screenshot) should work fine on your phone. Stupid question: Have you tried to clear the cache on your phone?

Comment: Just did, still doesnt work, if anything Im guessing this is a problem on netlify's end, if its not working only for iOS devices

Comment: will try it on my iPhone tomorrow.